# JVM property in JAVA

Tags: java, web-applications, websphere

A scenario  -  an EAR is installed on Websphere app  server and running at more than 30 JVMs. I want to create a property only at one JVM and want to read that in my java code.
How can i create a JVM level property by WAS console and read it in Java.

Comment: With 30 instances I suggest you examine [Apache Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/).

Comment: You can use JNDI Instead.. Would be available over 30 JVMs by creating  it at cluster level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating custom propery**

In WAS (server1) or the deployment manager admin console, navigate to 
Servers > ServerTypes > WebSphere application servers  cutom property
And Click on the JVM on which you want to create the

Server Infrastructure (section) > Java and Process Management > Process definition

Additional Properties (section) > Java Virtual Machine > Cutom Properties

Click the ‘New’ button to add a new custom property.

[image]

Click ‘Apply’.
Click ‘Save’ directly to the master configuration.

In a stand-alone or single node environment, you need to stop and restart your server for the changes to take effect.

In a clustered environment, where you defined the property in the deployment manager, you’ll probably want to do a ‘full resynchronize’ and restart the cluster.

---

- Accessing through Java code

  ---

After defining custom property within a WebSphere Application server or node where you defined the property, you can access its value just like you would a system property in Java, like this:

```
String custProperty = System.getProperty("wbe.home");
```

You can similarly use a scriptlet in a JSP page like this:

```
<%
String custProperty = System.getProperty("wbe.home");
if ( custProperty .equalsIgnoreCase("home") ) {
%>
```

If you want to automate the manual task of adding custom property to 30 JVM's
You can use Jython script . You can modify according to your requirement.

```
server = sys.argv[0]
property = sys.argv[1]
value = sys.argv[2]
if (len(sys.argv) == 4):
    descr = sys.argv[3]
else :
    descr = None

# Convert a list of items separated by linefeeds into an array
def getListArray(l):
    return l.splitlines()

# Obtain the "simple" server name
def getServerName(s):
    return AdminConfig.showAttribute(s, 'name')

# Add common attr list to specified Server's JVM
def addPropertiesToServer(s):
    jvm = AdminConfig.list('JavaVirtualMachine', s)

    # Look for existing property so we can replace it (by removing it first)
    currentProps = getListArray(AdminConfig.list("Property", jvm))
    for prop in currentProps:
        if property == AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, "name"):
            print "Removing existing property from Server %s" % getServerName(s)
            AdminConfig.remove(prop)

    # Store new property in 'systemProperties' object
    print "Adding property to Server %s" % getServerName(s)
    AdminConfig.modify(jvm,[['systemProperties',attr]])

# Construct list with new property name and value
attr = []

if (descr is None):
    print "Adding property %s=%s" % (property,value)
    attr.append([['name',property],['value',value]])
else:
    print "Adding property %s=%s,%s" % (property,value,descr)
    attr.append([['name',property],['value',value],['description',descr]])

# Locate all Application Servers if server is 'all'
if (server == 'all'):
    servers = AdminConfig.list('Server')
    for aServer in getListArray(servers):
        type = AdminConfig.showAttribute(aServer,'serverType')
        if (type == 'APPLICATION_SERVER'):
            addPropertiesToServer(aServer)

# TODO: support comma-separated list of servers

else:
    # Locate specified Server and its JVM
    server = AdminConfig.getid('/Server:'+server+'/')
    addPropertiesToServer(server)

# Save changes
if (AdminConfig.hasChanges()):
    AdminConfig.save()
```

Comment: If you have to apply this to 30 servers in ND you should script it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the WebSphere Variable at the cluster level on which your servers are running from:

```
Environment --> WebSphere Variable --> <SelectYour_cluster_From_Dropdown> --> New
```

Say, if, the variable name is "MY.CUSTOM.PROPERTY" then you can access it in your java code by writing following code:

```
String myCustomProperty = (String) System.getenv("MY.CUSTOM.PROPERTY");
```

Hope this works for you.